# Can't upgrade vrom ubuntu 17.10 to 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I'm trying yo update from 17.10 with

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

But i get a message  which says ther is nothing to update.

Comment: Why are you using the `-d` flag?

Comment: following instruccions..

Comment: Re-read those instructions. Or find better instructions to follow. The `-d` flag says that you want to install the next pre-release (**d**evelopment) version of Ubuntu. Since 18.04 has already been released, you're asking for something else...

Comment: Check [18.04 release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_17.10.)